# Output is not my ideal thing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Output is not my ideal thing.I wanna make drill down buttons.
Now output is
[image: current output]

index.html is

```
<html>　
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="chosen.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <select  data-placeholder="Choose" class="chzn-select" style="width:350px;">
      <option value="0">---</option>
      <option value="1" selected>A</option>
      <option value="2">B</option>
      <option value="3">C</option>
      <option value="3">D</option>
    </select>
    <select name="type" id="type1">
      <option value="1">a-1</option>
      <option value="2">a-2</option>
      <option value="3">a-3</option>
      <option value="4">a-4</option>
    </select>
    <select name="type" id="type2">
      <option value="5">b-1</option>
      <option value="6">b-2</option>
      <option value="7">b-3</option>
      <option value="8">b-4</option>
      <option value="9">b-5</option>
    </select>
    <select name="type" id="type3">
      <option value="10">c-1</option>
      <option value="11">c-2</option>
    </select>
    <select name="type" id="type4">
      <option value="10">d-1</option>
      <option value="11">d-2</option>
      <option value="11">d-3</option>
    </select>
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(".chzn-select").chosen();
    $(".chzn-select-deselect").chosen({allow_single_deselect:true});
  </script>
</html>
```

I wanna make only 2 drill down buttons in index.html .And  if I select A in first button,a-1~4 is shown in second button.If I select B in first button,b-1~5 is shown in second button.If I select C in first button,c-1~2 is shown in second button・・・・.

So output now is different form my ideal one.I use Chosen in jQuery plugin. Why can't I do my ideal this? What is wrong? Why can't I filter to second button?

Comment: @Teemu  yes, i wanna do so.but I cannot understand how to write it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps..

```
<html>　
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--    <script type="text/javascript" src="chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="chosen.css" rel="stylesheet">-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <select id="mainDD" data-placeholder="Choose" class="chzn-select" style="width:350px;">
      <option value="0">---</option>
      <option value="1">A</option>
      <option value="2">B</option>
      <option value="3">C</option>
      <option value="4">D</option>
    </select>
      <select name="type" id="type1">
      <option value="1">a-1</option>
      <option value="2">a-2</option>
      <option value="3">a-3</option>
      <option value="4">a-4</option>
    </select>
      <select name="type" id="type2">
      <option value="5">b-1</option>
      <option value="6">b-2</option>
      <option value="7">b-3</option>
      <option value="8">b-4</option>
      <option value="9">b-5</option>
    </select>
    <select name="type" id="type3">
      <option value="10">c-1</option>
      <option value="11">c-2</option>
    </select>
    <select name="type" id="type4">
      <option value="10">d-1</option>
      <option value="11">d-2</option>
      <option value="11">d-3</option>
    </select>

  <script type="text/javascript">
//    $(".chzn-select").chosen();
//    $(".chzn-select-deselect").chosen({allow_single_deselect:true});

        $(document).ready(function () {           

            $('#mainDD').on('change', function() {
              console.log($(this).val());
              console.log($('#mainDD :selected').text()) ;

              var thisType = "type" + $(this).val();              

              for(i=1; i<5; i++) {
                  var thisId = "type" + i;                  
                  console.log(thisType + " " + thisId);                  
                  if(thisType !== thisId) {
                    $("#"+thisId).hide();
                  }
                  else {
                    $("#"+thisId).show();
                  }
              }

            })

        });


  </script>

  </body>
</html>
```